# Working with MacOS UserDefaults using C++?

Tags: c++, macos, userdefaults

I am working on a `C++` project that needs to save data to a persistent storage on the operating system.
For `MacOS`, I want to save the data to UserDefaults - is there a `C++` library to manipulate them? Similar to `NSUserDefaults` in `Objective-C`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are plain C functions in CoreFoundation which you can use directly, the `CFPreference*` family, but they might be rather awkward to use. See for example [CFPreferencesSetAppValue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1515528-cfpreferencessetappvalue?language=objc) and the `CFPreferenceCopy*` and `CFPreferenceGet*` functions. You're going to have to convert C++ from/to CoreFoundation data types.

You probably want to write some convenience wrappers. In that case, writing an Objective-C++ file and accessing `NSUserDefaults` instead might be an option.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I only needed to read and write simple textual data so I ended up using an `Objective-C++` file (`.m`) that used the `NSUserDefaults` class to save and load it.